# Approximating Uniform Distribution with Mixture of Gaussians

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution, approximation

Let $T$ be a compact, connected, proper subset of $\mathbb{R}^3:\quad T \subset \mathbb{R}^3$.

Further let $\left\{ \boldsymbol{\mu}_i \right\}_{i=1}^n$ be a given finite set of $n$ point in $T$:
$$
\left\{ \boldsymbol{\mu}_i \right\}_{i=1}^n \subset T
$$

I would like to approximate continuous uniform distribution $u(\boldsymbol{x})$ over $T$ with mixture of Gaussians $g(\boldsymbol{x})$, having general, not necessarily diagonal covariances, and for which means of components are given by the set $\left\{ \boldsymbol{\mu}_i \right\}_{i=1}^n$, that is:
$$
g(\boldsymbol{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \pi_{i} \mathcal{N}(\boldsymbol{x} \,|\, \boldsymbol{\mu}_{i},\Sigma_{i})
$$

We can assume that, informally speaking, means $\left\{ \boldsymbol{\mu}_i \right\}_{i=1}^n$ are "equispaced" over $T$ or "nice" enough such that good approximation exists.

Any ideas on this?

The way I want to attack this is by minimizing some sort of computationally tractable divergence (Kullback–Leibler divergence, for example) between $u$ and $g$.

I'm curious if something similar was attempted before (searching the web didn't yield anything)?

Or could you point me to the relevant literature on this? Basically, any suggestions would be of help.

**Motivation**: this problem arises as an inverse problem in radiotherapy treatment planning. $T$ is considered to be a tumor and needs to receive radiation dose that is uniformly distributed over $T$. Dose spillage outside $T$ is undesirable. In this case the problem of designing such treatment can be reduced to estimating values of weights $\; \pi_1,\, \dots,\, \pi_n\;$ and covariance matrices $\; \Sigma_1,\, \dots,\, \Sigma_n$.

Comment: A major problem with this suggestion is that the Normal components are distributed over $\mathbb{R}^3$ rather than the support $T$.

Comment: @Xi'an The context suggests the intention is to truncate these Gaussians to $T$, but indeed this deserves clarification from the OP, especially in light of the "dose spillage remark."  That suggests a different abstract formulation of the problem, to wit: find $\pi_i$ and $\Sigma_i$ for which $g|_T$ stays within acceptable bounds while some norm of $g$ restricted to the complement of $T$ does not exceed a given threshold.  It's difficult to see why uniformity *per se* should be the objective. It's surprising, too, that $n$ and the $\mu_i$ are prescribed and not free variables.

Comment: @whuber, No formulation, as stated, is to approximate $u$ with $g$, or more precisely find $\text{argmin}_{\left\{\pi_i \right\}_{i=1}^n,\, \left\{\Sigma_i \right\}_{i=1}^n} {d\left( u, g \right)}$, where $d(\, \cdot \,,\, \cdot \, )$ is some divergence between $u$ and $g$ **over all of $\mathbb{R}^3$**, that also needs to be determined.

Comment: @whuber, If allowing $n$ and $\mu_i$ to vary freely makes solving problem (formulated as above) easier, then that is also fine

Comment: Uniform per se, comes from the nature of the problem, where we want to deliver uniformly distributed radiation dose inside the tumor $T$, while minimizing exposure to radiation of healthy tissues outside the tumor.

Comment: The issue is this: you cannot achieve both objectives of a uniform distribution inside $T$ and no radiation outside $T$. Therefore you *must* specify a trade-off between those objectives.  If you cleave to the "do no harm" principle then you will work hard to keep the outside dose low, at the cost of some variation of radiation within $T$.  Surely there are biophysically meaningful ways to measure how harmful the outside radiation is and how harmful variation within-$T$ radiation is. Use those to formulate your objective function. Add in a cost for large $n$, *etc.*

Comment: BTW, an attractive solution method would be spatial simulated annealing.

Comment: @whuber, "cannot achieve both objectives of a uniform distribution inside $T$ and no radiation outside $T$" - please read question carefully, that was never the objective. As I stated before, the objective is to minimize divergence between $u$ and $g$ **over all of $\mathbb{R}^3$**. What kind of divergence is part of the question. Finally, I think that the tradeoff you've described is already implicitly captured in the current formulation of the problem, as long as divergence is a proper metric. Actually, even quasimetric (such as KL-divergence) will suffice.

Comment: I seriously doubt a statistical measure of divergence over $\mathbb{R}^3$ has any physical or biological meaning: it's unclear what divergence might measure; it does not respect the dual goals of uniformity in $T$ and small values outside $T$; and it does not account for the fact that a person is not all of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  At best it would be an approximation of what you really need to be optimizing and at worst it would give wildly wrong answers--so why not formulate the problem you *should* be solving rather than beginning with an approximation that might or might not be relevant?

Comment: @aberdysh I have a very similar problem before me with the only difference, that I am considering a multidimensional space (dim = approx. 20) and my subset is a multidimensional rectangular. Have you by chance found a good algorithm for the problem?